# Ubuntu freeze when google chrome or vscode starts on Ryzen 5 5500u

Tags: 20.04, freeze, amd-ryzen

I have recently bought a laptop, Acer aspire 7 with ryzen 5 5500u 3200 mhz 16 GB ram and GTX 1650.

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

After installation whenever I try to start google chrome or VSCODE the laptop freezes.

Even the cursor does not move.

So I looked at the system monitor and whenever the laptop froze the 3 or 4 processors go to 100% and gets stuck.

I have to restart the laptop with power button every time it gets stuck.

The kernel version is 5.11.

I don't know if it is a common  issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: The current kernel used by 20.04 is not well suited for the 5500u. You will probably want to install 21.04 or, if you're comfortable with RCs, the soon-to-be-released 21.10. This may resolve the CPU usage patterns that you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Would it help if i use more updated kernel like 5.14 through ubuntu mainline kernel installer?

Comment: I have this issue using ZorinOS 16 pro on a new but low powered laptop. When using VSCode and working on a SPA that is being debugged in either Chrome or Edge, VSCode locks up, shows a dialog whether to wait or quit. Sometimes it will come around and sometimes I just hit the power button.

Comment: installed POPos 21.04 which is based on ubuntu and i not facing the issue anymore